# Knockout.js - Conditional value based on item position in the model data

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to figure out how to get access to the current index that is being bound. I don't care about the model itself, I want to execute a function if the current observable array item is at index X. Is this possible?

I have a fiddle going for a visual reference at http://jsfiddle.net/cmschick/hyHQW/2/.

The problem I am trying to solve is I need the column widths to match. Right now I have two tables but I would like to just have one, that would automatically take care of the widths but then my problem is how do I add the text "Allergies" on row 0, cell 0 and the text "Adverse reactions" on row X cell 0...

Hopefully there is a trick that I'm not considering. I really don't want to create the markup on the server side. Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I would suggest something like: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/knockoutjs/LbfktgENJPk/discussion to maintain an index on the items in an observableArray.

It looks like you are returning arrays from dependentObservables, so that won't quite do it.

Another thought would when you are building your `result` in your dependentObservables, keep track of an index whenever you add a row and when you actually push the row to the result, push an object like: `{ data: row, index: currentIndex }`.  Then bind against `data.x` or do a `data-bind="with: data"`

Comment: Hi RP, I tried what you suggested but when inspecting the DOM in Chrome's developer tools the hidden field I added and which binds to $data.index has a value of "".. Am I referencing it correctly with $data.index?

Comment: Do you have an updated fiddle with your code?  You are pushing in several spots, so you would need to make sure that the index is attached properly.  `$data.index` or just `index` would be correct.

Comment: Hi RP, Sorry I apparently changed the address of the Fiddle. Here is the correct address. http://jsfiddle.net/cmschick/hyHQW/

Comment: Your index is attached to each row item.  Where you are accessing it is inside the `foreach` on the cells.  You can use `$parent.index` to access items one scope level up.  Also, you would want to use the `text` binding instead of `value` on your span for testing.

Comment: Ah. $parent That makes sense. I was looking through the documentation pages for $data to see what other "keywords" are exposed but did not find any. That certainly helps a bunch. I'm starting to think that other than trial and error it might just be best to pull the debug copy and try to understand the code better because based on some of the other posts you've made to help people there is quite a bit that is not documented. I changed the hidden field to a span forgot to change the attribute. Thanks again you're a big help.

Comment: docs will be coming for 1.3 soon.  they are definitely necessary.

Comment: Thanks to Ryan I think I finally got what I was after. If anyone is interested in seeing the end result take a look at the updated fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/cmschick/hyHQW/

Answer (score 0):

Regarding:

> Right now I have two tables but I would like to just have one, that
>   would automatically take care of the widths but then my problem is how
>   do I add the text "Allergies" on row 0, cell 0 and the text "Adverse
>   reactions" on row X cell 0...

... if you use nested templates - a main template to render the general person info and table structure which then calls one to render the allergies and one to render the adverse reactions, you may find you don't need to go to such lengths and it may simplify your issues. I had similar issues and it certainly worked well for me!